# How to do an OR query with rails sunspot for rsolr

Tags: sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm having trouble finding an example of how to do an OR query with sunspot.  Here's my code.

```
class JobSearch < ActiveRecord::Base
  monetize :salary, as: 'salary', allow_nil: true
  DEFAULT_DISTANCE_IN_MILES = 50

  def search(page, page_size)
    latitude, longitude = LatitudeLongitudeLookup.latitude_longitude_from_string(location) if location.present?
    Job.search(include: [:state]) do
      facet(:minimum_compensation_cents) do
        row(150000..Float::INFINITY) do
          with(:minimum_compensation_cents).greater_than(150000)
        end
        row(100000..149999) do
          with(:minimum_compensation_cents, 100000..149999)
        end
        row(50000..99999) do
          with(:minimum_compensation_cents, 50000..99999)
        end
        row(25000..49999) do
          with(:minimum_compensation_cents, 25000..49999)
        end
      end

      facet :titles, limit: 5
      facet :city_state, limit: 5
      facet :job_type
      facet :work_remotely

      if !include_remote
        with(:location).in_radius(latitude, longitude, DEFAULT_DISTANCE_IN_MILES, bbox: true) if latitude && longitude
      else #need to do a location with an OR include_remote
        with(:location).in_radius(latitude, longitude, DEFAULT_DISTANCE_IN_MILES, bbox: true) if latitude && longitude
        #OR - how to do that?
        with(:work_remotely, true)
      end

      with(:city_state, location) if location.present? && (!latitude && !longitude)
      order_by_geodist(:location, latitude, longitude) if latitude && longitude
      with(:job_type, job_type) if job_type.present?
      with(:titles, position_title) if position_title.present?

      if !latitude && !longitude && !include_remote 
        with(:work_remotely, include_remote)
      end

      fulltext keyword
      paginate page: page, per_page: page_size
    end
  end
end
```

What I need to do is is directly under the facet section if they have searched on a location and also indicated to include remote jobs, the query should be something like "where location=locationsearchtext OR work_remotely=true".  So, how do you construct that with sunspot?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

```
facet :work_remotely

      if !include_remote
        with(:location).in_radius(latitude, longitude, DEFAULT_DISTANCE_IN_MILES, bbox: true) if latitude && longitude
      else #need to do a location with an OR include_remote
        any_of do
          with(:location).in_radius(latitude, longitude, DEFAULT_DISTANCE_IN_MILES, bbox: true) if latitude && longitude
          with(:work_remotely, true)
        end
      end
```

You can find out more information on the sunspot wiki:
https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Scoping-by-attribute-fields#disjunctions-and-conjunctions

Comment: Thank you.  However when I try this I get back no results.  When I filter on a location and include_remote meaning location OR include_remote, I get back zero results - even though I have 12 jobs in the index where work_remotely is true.  Here's the query that rails is outputting for the solr request. parameters={fq: ["Job", "work_remotely_b:true", "city_state_s:Bayerburgh, DC"]  It "looks" like it's just running an AND query.  How can I tell for sure that it's running an OR query?  Thanks.

Comment: Well, for an OR query, it should look something like this:
={fq: ["type:Supplier", "(master_town_ids_sm:({:name=>"Ashford", :county_name=>"Surrey"}) OR _query_:"{!geofilt sfield=location_ll pt=51.1,-4.1 d=50}")" so, the "OR" should be visible. Have you reindexed after adding this line?

Comment: Yes, I've reindexed a few times.

Comment: I think I may have an idea why it't not working but I need to do quite a bit of code update as to how our index is created with fake data first.

Comment: ok cool.. i think fake data should not make a difference because when we reindex, it should index all the necessary data that is present in our database.

Comment: Look closely at the search method and see it first tries to look up the lat/long of the location.  In my case we were using faker to create our locations so no lat/long was being returned so it fell into the with(:city_state, location) part near the end of the method where it looks for just a regular text match.  I've reworked my seed file to use real city/states and now it's getting into the any_of portion but I'm getting an error - wrong number of arguments (6 for 5) on this line -  with(:location).in_radius(latitude, longitude, DEFAULT_DISTANCE_IN_MILES, bbox: true) if latitude && longitude

Comment: ok yes, that makes sense. Just check if latitude and longitude are being calculated properly, and maybe even put in static values for latitude and longitude in the facet : with(:location).in_radius(latitude, longitude, DEFAULT_DISTANCE_IN_MILES, bbox: true) to check if that is where the error is occurring.

Comment: If I comment out any_of do, with(:work_remotely, true) and end leaving only the location it works fine.  I am in fact getting a valid lat/long, so something is wrong with putting it in the any_of in conjunction with the work_remotely.  Ever seen anything like this before?  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I just tried taking out bbox and then it worked.  Any idea why?

Comment: ok.. thats strange.. havent really tried bbox with any_of do.. will let you know when i do try...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80691/discussion-between-amitejkalra-and-geoff-swartz).